# LINQ to SQL how to use it in .ashx file to generate json?

Tags: database, json, linq, linq-to-sql, ashx

I have some problem to Figure out how to use LINQ to SQL in .ashx file to generate json?
I am able to generate json using this code but I need to select TaskName and createdOn columns. can someone help me how to  select TaskName and createdOn columns to  generate json?

```
        //DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        //var tasksCreatedOm = from c in db.Tasks
        //                     select c.createdOn;

        //the bloack will get all data in table 
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
        context.Response.Write(new SchedulerAjaxData(new  DataClasses1DataContext().Tasks));
```

My Tasks Class
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following (untested):

```
using(DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    var tasksCreatedOn = from c in db.Tasks
                        select new { c.taskName, c.createdOn };

    // This block will get all data in table 
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
    context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(tasksCreatedOn));
}
```

First I projected your Tasks into an anonymous type containing `taskName` and `createdOn`. Then I used the `JavaScriptSerializer` to serialize them to JSON. I also added a `using` block so that the `DataContext` is disposed of properly.